# Laravel multiple model bound forms in a parent view

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

The overall concept that I'm attempting to do is create admin panel that has multiple "forms" on a single blade view.  Each "form" is a blade.php file that has a form that is model bound to provide quick access to the model data on load.  For example, let's say that I'm running a manufacturing line and there are three models (subviews) that I want to @include() on manufacturing.blade.php.

- Parent view (manufacturing.blade.php)

  - Subview - Start time (start-time.blade.php)
  - Subview - Throughput (throughput.blade.php)
  - Subview - Supervisor (supervisor.blade.php)

Each subview has a submit button on it that POSTS to the assigned resource controller.  My problem is how do I successfully load manufacturing.blade.php and include form model binding when I never call the index controller on the subviews.

Is what I'm asking even possible?

Comment: You might be able to get away with just fetching the form data within the blade.php file. Just use a <?php> tag

Comment: another option is to use view composers

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I figured it out right after I posted the question.  The variables required for the model binding inside the subviews were the problem.  I was receiving errors about the variables not available, blah.... when I loaded the parent view page.  Obviously the variables aren't available when I call the subviews because they were never pulled in from the parent view.  In other words I'm trying to access something that isn't there.

Solution:
In the parent view loading controller, perform all the necessary db call to obtain/generate the objects required for the subviews.  After the objects are obtained use

```
View::share('startTime', $startTime);
View::share('throughput', $throughput);
View::share('supervisor', $supervisor);
```

That method (view::share) allows that variable, 'startTime', etc..., to be shared across all the blade views that reside inside of parent.  Just be sure you add the lines right before you return the intended parent view from your controller.